# How to render component regardless of the props change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I hope the title makes sense but this React lifecycle method is quite confusing by the nature.

I can't re-render the new component because of the previous prop changes. (props.error is NOT undefined)

Explanation

- Once error is occured in componentDidMount, props.error becomes 'STRING'
- First time, it `goBack()` and works fine.
- Second time but when we open this component again, because props.error is STRING(not undefined), it doesn't render and go back,

HOW do I make it render the component?

```
  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props: Props, state: State): State | null {
    const {
      error,
    } = props;
    
    // Once error is occured in componentDidMount, props.error is not undefined.
    // First time, it works and go back to the previous page.
    // But when we open this component again, it doesn't render and go back, because props.error is NOT undefined.
    // componentDidMount still gets triggered to fetch, but it gets triggers AFTER this
    if (error) {
      goBack(); //// I MUST call this (This hide or unmount the current component)
    }
    ...
  }
  componentDidMount() {
     fetch() // this causes an error and update props.error (from undefined to 'STRING')
  }
```

Comment: When fetch triggers an error, how do you set the `error` prop? Is it the state of a parent component?

Comment: Clear the `error` state of a parent component, when you call `goBack`

Answer (score 0):

Clear the `error` state of a parent component, when you call `goBack`